Run an app on my rooted phone as another device
I just rooted my phone and installed LineageOS. I managed to install Masgisk, even though it was not clearly documented.
The only reason why I wanted to root my phone is so that I can run on my Pixel 4a (5G) a specific app that is only approved for the Pixel 6 and the Pixel 7. I'm very sure that it can run on a Pixel 4. It's locked to these two versions for administrative reasons. What I kept hearing was, "You'll need to root your phone to do that."
I tried installing it via the APK as well. That works but when it starts, it still refuses to run because I'm on the wrong device.
With a rooted phone that has Magisk installed (but no modules for Magisk), how can I do that?
I looked into several modules, but none of them seemed to work. I could not install lsposed, MagiskHide, or Zygisk. I don't know what they are, but they were mentioned on some websites that I found.
Does anyone know I can do this, or did I root my phone for nothing?
UPDATE: I got lsposed installed.
There is the app, as requested in the comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.insulet.myblue.pdm It needs FDA approval for any platform it's released on, and that takes months or years. But the app itself is very likely to work on any phone that's recent enough.
Without the app, I have to carry a whole second device around that's the size of a phone. It can run out of battery. I can forget to bring it with me. Overall, I'd feel much safer with the app. I'll decompile and recompile it if I have to.

Which app are you talking about? Please link it from Play store//I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible unless you decompile the apk make changes and sign it (something I never did)

@beeshyams I linked the app in the update above. It may not be visible outside of the US.

In case if medical apps the restriction is indeed usually just a precaution of the manufacturer so theoretically you might be able to get it to run. Unfortunately finding out how an app detected the phone model can be different for each app. For a permanent bypass Zygisk/Lsposed is an option but for developing such a bypass it can get pretty hard. For fast and simple tests I recommend https://frida.re as it allows to modify an app on the fly so development is about a hundred times faster than for Lsposed.

If it only runs on specific device models, then I'd guess it checks for the device model. There's an old Q&A similar to this topic: How to change device model in build.prop?. I don't recommend modifying the file directly and instead utilize what Magisk may provide, but I don't have any devices rooted, so I can't really comment on how to do it particularly, sorry.

@AndrewT. I will try those. Thank you.

@Robert I will try those. Thank you.
